# Get value of checked radio button in radio button in Angular JS which as ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Here is the code on selection of any one of the radio button i need to get the value

```
<label ng-repeat="SurveyType in SurveyTypes">
    <input type="radio" name="SurveyTypeName" ng-model="surveyData.SurveyTypeName" ng-value="{{surveyData.SurveyTypeName}}" />
    {{SurveyType.Name}} &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
</label>
```

Comment: The value should be updated once someone clicks a radio button. Check $scope.surveyData.SurveyTypeName 's value

Comment: basically you don't even need `{{}}` on `ng-value`, try `ng-value="surveyData.SurveyTypeName"`

Answer (score 1):

You should assign `value` from your `repeat-loop` not from `model` value and no need to use `{{}}` for `ng-value`

so use `ng-value="SurveyType.Name"` instead of `ng-value="{{surveyData.SurveyTypeName}}"` so selected radio button value set to `surveyData.SurveyTypeName`.

If you want to select anyone by default you can assign value to `surveyData.SurveyTypeName` like `$scope.surveyData={SurveyTypeName: 'second'}` then that radio button shown as selected that has value `second`.

**HTML:**

```
<label ng-repeat="SurveyType in SurveyTypes">
    <input type="radio" name="SurveyTypeName" ng-model="surveyData.SurveyTypeName" ng-value="SurveyType.Name" />
    {{SurveyType.Name}} &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
</label>
```

[PLUNKER DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/bOwx7J5xD39rRsUPQEy2?p=preview)

Comment: $scope.surveyData.SurveyTypeName as undefined

Comment: In controller you should create first `$scope.surveyData` as object like `$scope.surveyData= {}` then  `$scope.surveyData.SurveyTypeName = "sonthing"` or `$scope.surveyData= {SurveyTypeName: 'something'};` see PLUNKER DEMO

Comment: same error.Here the SurveyTypes is coming from Database

Comment: Can you show your controller code? (update your question with controller code)

Comment: $scope.Submit = function () {
        var surveyData = {
            SurveyTypeName: $scope.surveyData.SurveyTypeName,
        };

Comment: before `$scope.Submit` function declare  `$scope.surveyData= {SurveyTypeName: 'something'};` here `something` can be empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML should be like this.

```
 <input type="radio" name="SurveyTypeName" ng-model="surveyData.SurveyTypeName" ng-value="{{surveyData.SurveyTypeName}}"  ng-change="getval($index)"/>
```

Js

```
$scope.getval = function (index){


 var servetypename =SurveyTypes[index];

var data =servetypename.SurveyTypeName

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know from `surveyData.SurveyTypeName` is coming from.

```
<li ng-repeat="SurveyType in SurveyTypes">
        <input type="radio" name="SurveyTypeName" ng-model="$parent.rdoSelected" ng-value="SurveyType.SurveyTypeName" />
        {{SurveyType.Name}}
</li>
```

[**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/WQKJxEYohVXq3mrwCu6m?p=preview)

Comment: $scope.surveyData.SurveyTypeName as undefined

Comment: it is $scope.surveyData.SurveyTypeName defined in Js